# performSegueWithIdentifier is giving runtime error, why?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a ViewController with a containerView and the ContainerViewController has a modal segue to another ViewController. I have the segue identifier as "embedConverter", now when the ContainerViewController's viewDidLoad method is called, I have the following commands:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"embedConverter" sender:nil];
}
```

I am getting a runtime error when the performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: method is called. I am just now starting to learn to use this method so Im not really sure what could be causing this to happen. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Here is the error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

And yes, I want it to segue immediately, I will have other segues as well but for now I just have one.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.containerViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"embedConverter" sender:nil];
}
```

this is the viewDidLoad for my main ViewController. containerViewController is the view that is embedded in the ContainerView.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: You do realize that in your viewcontroller according to your code will basically segue immediately as it loads?

Comment: Please post the error log so that we can get a clear idea about whats going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Two things. 1. Why don't you directly Call `embedConverter`? 2. Its not segue problem, I guess you are using some c++ library in the ViewController you are calling from the segue that is giving runtime error.

Comment: I agree with @Goppinath's answer. I also advise to changing the nil portion of your code to self. So, [self performSegue...sender:self]; I doubt it will do anything, but it doesn't hurt

Comment: @iphonic what do you mean by call directly? I want to be able to switch between different view controllers in the background, and show them later on. the one I am referring to in my question is the default view which is why it gets segued immediately. also I am not using any c++ code, it is only Objective-C.

Comment: please post your error stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** I strongly suggest to move your,

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"embedConverter" sender:nil];
```

portion of your code to UIVIewController's

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

I hope it will help you

**Reason:** I can't exactly explain why, but you have to let your UIViewController to load fully first before you trigger an extra navigation or presentation.

Comment: Just tried this, it does not solve the problem, I will posted the code that I used.

Comment: oh sorry, I read it as viewDidLoad. I had tried this previously as well, I will change the code to reflect that.

Comment: Hmm... before when I tried it it gave me the same error but now I tried it again and it is working, thanks for the help.